# unable to ssh login to new vm with Ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-inventory

I am not able to login with ssh with Ansible on a newly created VM. I am getting below error

> UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the
>   host via ssh:
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@
>   WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
>   @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\nIT
>   IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!\r\nSomeone could be
>   eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!\r\nIt is
>   also possible that a host key has just been changed.\r\nThe
>   fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host
>   is\nSHA256:V48LPZh5wKQhWTF456KVN24LQLYOESAKmJgdKCe6Eho.\r\nPlease
>   contact your system administrator.\r\nAdd correct host key in
>   /home/naresh-openkey/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this
>   message.\r\nOffending ECDSA key in
>   /home/naresh-openkey/.ssh/known_hosts:128\r\n  remove with:\r\n 
>   ssh-keygen -f \"/home/naresh-openkey/.ssh/known_hosts\" -R
>   12.44.343.64\r\nPassword authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.\r\nKeyboard-interactive authentication is
>   disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.\r\nPermission denied
>   (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}

I tried below solution

- export the key

  export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
- Add `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False` in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg under `[defaults]`

I am using a custom `inventory.yaml`

Comment: try after deleting the line `128` from the `know_hosts` file

Comment: well i i don't want to do that. I want the process to be automated

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem for an application, were my keys changed constantly and I was sure that no security issues could arise by ignoring the hostkey.

**But be sure that this is the case before you start ignoring the warning!**

In your custom inventory add the following variable:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'
```

This applys to all hosts in your custom inventory. If are using specific groups, you can also use the groupname instead off *all*.

Comment: My custom inventory is a YAML file. But this seems to be .ini code. How can i add in custom yaml file ?

Comment: You can see a comparison between YAML and INI inventories here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Comment: `[ssh_connection]
# ssh arguments to use
ssh_args = -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

Comment: Worked for me after replacing **": "** by **"="** and using like this: `ansible_ssh_common_args='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'`